# Merging two datasets - Outer spatial join of MODIS and Drought Code data

Tags: geopandas, spatial-join

I have two data frames, one with Modis data and another is drought code data in the following format:

- **Modis Data**

```
modis_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    modis_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(modis_df['lat'], modis_df['lon']))
```

[image]

- **Drought Code**

```
drought_code_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    drought_code_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(drought_code_df['lat'], drought_code_df['lon']))
```

### [image]

I am required to get the merged output of two data as follows:

- Outer join the tables (Having data from both datasets - filled with NaN values for columns with no values)
- Join by the nearest location for a *given date* (Join on:YYYYMMDD)
- If no data exists for that date, include it in output with NaN in the corresponding merged column values for the other table.

---

Naively, I was thinking of something on the following fronts:

```
modis_gdf['geometry'] = modis_gdf.geometry.buffer(1.0)

dc_modis_ojoin = drought_code_gdf.merge(modis_gdf, how="outer", on="YYYYMMDD")\
    .loc[lambda d: d["geometry_y"]!=None & d["geometry_y"].contains(d["geometry_x"])]
```

The lambda function is incorrect, and gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

But the approach was: 1. Outer join based on date, 2. Filter out data if the point is not contained within the polygon.

I am new to this world of working with Pandas/GeoPandas.

Comment: I dont understand. What is your end goal?

Comment: I have datasets A, B, and C. The goal is to join them on DATE, so we have the data from the other datasets nearest by location for each date. If no such point is found, those column values should be NaN.

Comment: To add more clarity: the end goal is to perform join on these datasets based on spatial and attribute criteria simultaneously (using python).